# I would like to fadein/fadeout a list of terms from an array only once

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, break

I am trying to make some titles that will fade in and out of a landing page once and then not repeat. Here is the code I have been trying to use. Of course it repeats forever. I am a beginner and was trying to include a counter variable that would get the index number of the last item in the array, and when this number is reached, stop repeating. This way the the texts can be added to without needed to update the nth item number.

```
// after the last title in the array has been displayed, stop loop  
// +++++++++++++++++++ changeTitle

var titles = ["title zero", "title one", "title two", "title three",
    "title four", "title n"
];

function changeTitle() {  
    var ct = $("#title").data("term") || 0;

    $("#title").data("term", ct == titles.length - 1 ? 0 : ct + 1)
               .text(titles[ct])
               .fadeIn(200)
               .delay(500)
               .fadeOut(200, changeTitle);
}
$(changeTitle);
```

Comment: please provide html code also to reproduce your problem here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yLhhobey/)

```
jQuery.each(titles, function( index, value ) {
   $("#title").fadeIn(200).delay(500).fadeOut(200, function() {
               $("#title").text(value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Wonderful - thanks for the solution! Now I will learn about "each" and how that works. Of course I was looking for a complicated solution, but this way is much much better! :)

Answer (score 0):

Somehwhere in your html you should open a script tag and execute this once the **document is ready**. That is a commonJQuery Pattern

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        changeTitle();
    });
</script>
```

This should do the job. Since you're using jQuery anyway this does not introduce any new dependencies.